# Trouble with Logout Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my Logout Action :

```
        public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        Session.Clear();
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Session.Abandon();

        return RedirectToAction("Logpage", "Home");
    }
```

It works, but the only problem that after logout `Goback` button in navigator still working and it allow to Go back into last page before logout

Comment: That might be the **cached page on the browser** in which page no action required or you need to set the cache option for the page. Can they interact with the page?

Comment: Using fiddler, you can verify if on the back button, browser contacts the server at all. My guess is it does not hence, the page shown is the cached page on the browser.

Comment: No it's not the cached page on browser because i can even Excute action.

Comment: Are you sure that you have set the [Authorize] attribute on all of your relevant controller actions?  If it is not a cached page, then MVC doesn't think you need to be logged in to view the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expire the entire application's cache on the logout action; cache expiry must be set on every page individually.  Setting cache expiry only works for the logout view in this case, and probably doesn't affect the logpage because of the redirection (not 100% sure how it works with redirection).

Comment: How to set it for hole application?

Comment: Set the properties within the master/layout page, or set it in the controller, either through a base controller class, an action invoker, and I think it can be done in a global filter.  Something that affects all controllers...